I want to use RemoteSSH in an offline environment
I want to use RemoteSSH for VScode in an offline environment.
However, I can't help but go to download VS code Server.
The settings.jsom is below and useExecServer is set to false.
{
    "json.schemas": [

    ],
    "remote.SSH.useExecServer": false,
    "update.mode": "none",
    "extensions.autoUpdate": false,
    "extensions.autoCheckUpdates": false
}

Here's the error message.
[09:01:11.327] Got request to download on client for {"artifact":"server-linux-legacy-x64","destPath":"/home/opc/.vscode-server/bin/4849ca9bdf9666755eb463db297b69e5385090e3/vscode-server.tar.gz"}
[09:01:11.327] server download URL: https://update.code.visualstudio.com/commit:4849ca9bdf9666755eb463db297b69e5385090e3/server-linux-legacy-x64/stable
[09:01:11.327] Downloading VS Code server locally...
[09:01:32.340] Resolver error: Error: VS Code Server (Failed to fetch) をダウンロードできませんでした

I also tried placing downloaded files in the Internet environment at the connection, but to no avail.
[opc@testserver ~]$ ll .v
.viminfo        .vscode-server/
[opc@testserver ~]$ ll .vscode-server/
bin/                                                        vscode-cli-4849ca9bdf9666755eb463db297b69e5385090e3.tar.gz
[opc@testserver ~]$ ll .vscode-server/bin/4849ca9bdf9666755eb463db297b69e5385090e3/
code                              vscode-scp-done.flag
vscode_cli_alpine_x64_cli.tar.gz  vscode-server.tar.gz
[opc@testserver ~]$ ll .vscode-server/bin/4849ca9bdf9666755eb463db297b69e5385090e3/
total 29952
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 opc opc 21701432 Sep  4 13:08 code
-rw-r--r--. 1 opc opc  8964808 Sep 30 10:08 vscode_cli_alpine_x64_cli.tar.gz
-rw-rw-r--. 1 opc opc        0 Sep 30 10:50 vscode-scp-done.flag
-rw-rw-r--. 1 opc opc        0 Oct  1 00:01 vscode-server.tar.gz
[opc@testserver ~]$

The full output is below.
[09:01:07.395] Log Level: 2
[09:01:07.413] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+testserver", attempt 1
[09:01:07.415] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false
[09:01:07.415] "remote.SSH.useExecServer": false
[09:01:07.417] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[09:01:07.417] "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {}
[09:01:07.418] "remote.SSH.path": undefined
[09:01:07.418] "remote.SSH.configFile": undefined
[09:01:07.418] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[09:01:07.419] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[09:01:07.419] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[09:01:07.419] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[09:01:07.420] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[09:01:07.420] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[09:01:07.420] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
[09:01:07.420] "remote.SSH.enableDynamicForwarding": true
[09:01:07.421] "remote.SSH.enableRemoteCommand": false
[09:01:07.421] "remote.SSH.serverPickPortsFromRange": {}
[09:01:07.421] "remote.SSH.serverInstallPath": {}
[09:01:07.422] "remote.SSH.permitPtyAllocation": false
[09:01:07.422] "remote.SSH.preferredLocalPortRange: undefined
[09:01:07.422] "remote.SSH.useCurlAndWgetConfigurationFiles: false
[09:01:07.432] VS Code version: 1.93.0
[09:01:07.432] Remote-SSH version: remote-ssh@0.115.2024090921
[09:01:07.432] win32 x64
[09:01:07.436] SSH Resolver called for host: testserver
[09:01:07.436] Setting up SSH remote "testserver"
[09:01:07.442] Using commit id "4849ca9bdf9666755eb463db297b69e5385090e3" and quality "stable" for server
[09:01:07.449] Script variables:
 {
  "InstallExitCode.24": "AlreadyInProgress",
  "InstallExitCode.25": "ServerDownloadFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.26": "NoDownloaderAvailable",
  "InstallExitCode.27": "UnsupportedArch",
  "InstallExitCode.28": "StatusCheckFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.29": "NeedInsidersArch",
  "InstallExitCode.30": "NoDownloaderAvailableForStatusCheck",
  "InstallExitCode.31": "ServerTransferFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.32": "ServerFailedToStart",
  "InstallExitCode.33": "NeedInsidersWindows",
  "InstallExitCode.34": "CreateInstallDirFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.35": "UnsupportedPlatform",
  "InstallExitCode.36": "ServerTerminatedCVE20201416",
  "InstallExitCode.37": "UnpackFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.38": "ChangeDirFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.AlreadyInProgress": "24",
  "InstallExitCode.ServerDownloadFailed": "25",
  "InstallExitCode.NoDownloaderAvailable": "26",
  "InstallExitCode.NoDownloaderAvailableForStatusCheck": "30",
  "InstallExitCode.UnsupportedArch": "27",
  "InstallExitCode.StatusCheckFailed": "28",
  "InstallExitCode.NeedInsidersArch": "29",
  "InstallExitCode.ServerTransferFailed": "31",
  "InstallExitCode.ServerFailedToStart": "32",
  "InstallExitCode.NeedInsidersWindows": "33",
  "InstallExitCode.CreateInstallDirFailed": "34",
  "InstallExitCode.UnsupportedPlatform": "35",
  "InstallExitCode.ServerTerminatedCVE20201416": "36",
  "InstallExitCode.UnpackFailed": "37",
  "InstallExitCode.ChangeDirFailed": "38",
  "InstallUnpackCode.Success": "success",
  "InstallUnpackCode.Error": "error",
  "InstallUnpackCode.MissingFiles": "missingFiles",
  "uuid": "32739e016167",
  "startMarker": "32739e016167: running",
  "commitId": "4849ca9bdf9666755eb463db297b69e5385090e3",
  "quality": "stable",
  "token": "11a11111-11a1-111a-111a-aa111a1aa1aa",
  "vscodeAgentFolder": "$HOME/.vscode-server",
  "allowClientDownload": "1",
  "forceClientDownload": "0",
  "cliNameInArchive": "code",
  "ignoreWgetConfigFlag": " --no-config ",
  "ignoreCurlConfigFlag": " --disable ",
  "wgetTriesSegment": "--tries=1",
  "listenArgs": "--on-host=127.0.0.1 --on-port",
  "getDownloadServerStartTrigger": "32739e016167:trigger_server_download",
  "getDownloadServerEndTrigger": "32739e016167:trigger_server_download_end",
  "getProgressDownloading": "32739e016167%%1%%",
  "getProgressInstalling": "32739e016167%%2%%"
}
[09:01:07.453] Install and start server if needed
[09:01:10.109] Checking ssh with "C:\Windows\system32\ssh.exe -V"
[09:01:10.114] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Windows\system32\ssh.exe ENOENT
[09:01:10.114] Checking ssh with "C:\Windows\ssh.exe -V"
[09:01:10.116] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Windows\ssh.exe ENOENT
[09:01:10.116] Checking ssh with "C:\Windows\System32\Wbem\ssh.exe -V"
[09:01:10.117] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Windows\System32\Wbem\ssh.exe ENOENT
[09:01:10.118] Checking ssh with "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ssh.exe -V"
[09:01:10.119] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ssh.exe ENOENT
[09:01:10.119] Checking ssh with "C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe -V"
[09:01:10.168] > O
[09:01:10.169] > p
[09:01:10.169] > e
[09:01:10.169] > n
[09:01:10.170] > S
[09:01:10.170] > S
[09:01:10.170] > H
[09:01:10.170] > _
[09:01:10.171] > f
[09:01:10.171] > o
[09:01:10.171] > r
[09:01:10.171] > _
[09:01:10.172] > W
[09:01:10.173] > i
[09:01:10.173] > n
[09:01:10.173] > d
[09:01:10.174] > ows_8.1p1,
[09:01:10.174] >  LibreSSL 3.0.2

[09:01:10.180] Running script with connection command: "C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe" -T -D 56552 testserver bash
[09:01:10.182] Generated SSH command: 'type "C:\Users\ocs\AppData\Local\Temp\2\vscode-linux-multi-line-command-testserver-95118882.sh" | "C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe" -T -D 56552 testserver bash'
[09:01:10.184] Terminal shell path: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
[09:01:10.999] > 32739e016167: running
> ]0;C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
[09:01:10.999] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[09:01:11.013] > Acquiring lock on /home/opc/.vscode-server/bin/4849ca9bdf9666755eb463db297b69e5385090e3/vscode-remote-lock.opc.4849ca9bdf9666755eb463db297b69e5385090e3
[09:01:11.020] > Installing to /home/opc/.vscode-server/bin/4849ca9bdf9666755eb463db297b69e5385090e3...
> 32739e016167%%1%%
> Downloading with wget
[09:01:11.313] > wget download failed
> failed: Connection refused. failed: Network is unreachable.
> printenv:
>     SSH_CONNECTION=x.x.x.x 56556 x.x.x.x 22
>     MODULES_RUN_QUARANTINE=LD_LIBRARY_PATH LD_PRELOAD
>     LANG=en_US.UTF-8
>     S_COLORS=auto
>     which_declare=declare -f
>     XDG_SESSION_ID=1456
>     MODULES_CMD=/usr/share/Modules/libexec/modulecmd.tcl
>     USER=opc
>     SELINUX_ROLE_REQUESTED=
>     PWD=/home/opc/.vscode-server/bin/4849ca9bdf9666755eb463db297b69e5385090e3
>     HOME=/home/opc
>     SSH_CLIENT=x.x.x.x 56556 22
>     SELINUX_LEVEL_REQUESTED=
>     LOADEDMODULES=
>     SHELL=/bin/bash
>     SELINUX_USE_CURRENT_RANGE=
>     SHLVL=2
>     MANPATH=:
>     MODULEPATH=/etc/scl/modulefiles:/usr/share/Modules/modulefiles:/etc/modulefiles:/usr/share/modulefiles
>     LOGNAME=opc
>     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
>     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
>     MODULEPATH_modshare=/usr/share/Modules/modulefiles:2:/etc/modulefiles:2:/usr
> r/share/modulefiles:2
>     PATH=/home/opc/.local/bin:/home/opc/bin:/usr/share/Modules/bin:/usr/local/bi
> in:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin
>     MODULESHOME=/usr/share/Modules
>     LESSOPEN=||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
>     BASH_FUNC_which%%=() {  ( alias;
>      eval ${which_declare} ) | /usr/bin/which --tty-only --read-alias --read-fun
> nctions --show-tilde --show-dot $@
>     }
>     BASH_FUNC_module%%=() {  unset _mlshdbg;
>      if [ "${MODULES_SILENT_SHELL_DEBUG:-0}" = '1' ]; then
>      case "$-" in
>      *v*x*)
>      set +vx;
>      _mlshdbg='vx'
>      ;;
>      *v*)
>      set +v;
>      _mlshdbg='v'
>      ;;
>      *x*)
[09:01:11.326] > 
>      set +x;
>      _mlshdbg='x'
>      ;;
>      *)
>      _mlshdbg=''
>      ;;
>      esac;
>      fi;
>      unset _mlre _mlIFS;
>      if [ -n "${IFS+x}" ]; then
>      _mlIFS=$IFS;
>      fi;
>      IFS=' ';
>      for _mlv in ${MODULES_RUN_QUARANTINE:-};
>      do
>      if [ "${_mlv}" = "${_mlv##*[!A-Za-z0-9_]}" -a "${_mlv}" = "${_mlv#[0-9]}" ]
> ]; then
>      if [ -n "`eval 'echo ${'$_mlv'+x}'`" ]; then
>      _mlre="${_mlre:-}${_mlv}_modquar='`eval 'echo ${'$_mlv'}'`' ";
>      fi;
>      _mlrv="MODULES_RUNENV_${_mlv}";
>      _mlre="${_mlre:-}${_mlv}='`eval 'echo ${'$_mlrv':-}'`' ";
>      fi;
>      done;
>      if [ -n "${_mlre:-}" ]; then
>      eval `eval ${_mlre} /usr/bin/tclsh /usr/share/Modules/libexec/modulecmd.tcl
> l bash '"$@"'`;
>      else
>      eval `/usr/bin/tclsh /usr/share/Modules/libexec/modulecmd.tcl bash "$@"`;  
>      fi;
>      _mlstatus=$?;
>      if [ -n "${_mlIFS+x}" ]; then
>      IFS=$_mlIFS;
>      else
>      unset IFS;
>      fi;
>      unset _mlre _mlv _mlrv _mlIFS;
>      if [ -n "${_mlshdbg:-}" ]; then
>      set -$_mlshdbg;
>      fi;
>      unset _mlshdbg;
>      return $_mlstatus
>     }
>     BASH_FUNC_switchml%%=() {  typeset swfound=1;
>      if [ "${MODULES_USE_COMPAT_VERSION:-0}" = '1' ]; then
>      typeset swname='main';
>      if [ -e /usr/share/Modules/libexec/modulecmd.tcl ]; then
>      typeset swfound=0;
>      unset MODULES_USE_COMPAT_VERSION;
>      fi;
>      else
>      typeset swname='compatibility';
>      if [ -e /usr/share/Modules/libexec/modulecmd-compat ]; then
>      typeset swfound=0;
>      MODULES_USE_COMPAT_VERSION=1;
>      export MODULES_USE_COMPAT_VERSION;
>      fi;
>      fi;
>      if [ $swfound -eq 0 ]; then
>      echo "Switching to Modules $swname version";
>      source /usr/share/Modules/init/bash;
>      else
>      echo "Cannot switch to Modules $swname version, command not found";        
>      return 1;
>      fi
>     }
>     BASH_FUNC_scl%%=() {  if [ "$1" = "load" -o "$1" = "unload" ]; then
>      eval "module $@";
>      else
>      /usr/bin/scl "$@";
>      fi
>     }
>     BASH_FUNC_ml%%=() {  module ml "$@"
>     }
>     _=/usr/bin/printenv
>     OLDPWD=/home/opc
> Trigger local server download
> 32739e016167:trigger_server_download
> artifact==server-linux-legacy-x64==
> destFolder==/home/opc/.vscode-server/bin/==
> destFolder2==4849ca9bdf9666755eb463db297b69e5385090e3/vscode-server.tar.gz==    
> 32739e016167:trigger_server_download_end
> Waiting for client to transfer server archive...
> Waiting for /home/opc/.vscode-server/bin/4849ca9bdf9666755eb463db297b69e5385090e
> e3/vscode-server.tar.gz.done and vscode-server.tar.gz to exist
> 
[09:01:11.327] Got request to download on client for {"artifact":"server-linux-legacy-x64","destPath":"/home/opc/.vscode-server/bin/4849ca9bdf9666755eb463db297b69e5385090e3/vscode-server.tar.gz"}
[09:01:11.327] server download URL: https://update.code.visualstudio.com/commit:4849ca9bdf9666755eb463db297b69e5385090e3/server-linux-legacy-x64/stable
[09:01:11.327] Downloading VS Code server locally...
[09:01:32.340] Resolver error: Error: VS Code Server (Failed to fetch) をダウンロードできませんでした
    at v.Create (c:\Users\ocs\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.115.2024090921\out\extension.js:2:501404)
    at c:\Users\ocs\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.115.2024090921\out\extension.js:2:545104
    at async t.downloadAndCopyToHost (c:\Users\ocs\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.115.2024090921\out\extension.js:2:544604)
    at async c:\Users\ocs\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.115.2024090921\out\extension.js:2:615879
    at async t.tryInstall (c:\Users\ocs\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.115.2024090921\out\extension.js:2:616125)
    at async c:\Users\ocs\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.115.2024090921\out\extension.js:2:575788
    at async t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\ocs\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.115.2024090921\out\extension.js:2:579017)
    at async k (c:\Users\ocs\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.115.2024090921\out\extension.js:2:572574)
    at async t.resolve (c:\Users\ocs\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.115.2024090921\out\extension.js:2:576428)
    at async c:\Users\ocs\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.115.2024090921\out\extension.js:2:844812
[09:01:32.590] ------


Your question seems somewhat vague as you have omitted what exactly it is that you are trying to achieve. But it sounds as if you are simply trying to connect to a remote host using VS Code running on your local machine through ssh by using the VS Code Remote SSH extension. If this be the case, you can help others help you troubleshoot the problem by specifying the OS and VS Code version of your host machine, as well the OS of the remote host you are trying to log into. Also, it might be helpful if you can describe the steps to replicate the issue you are running into. That aside, it might be helpful to first understand what happens when you log into a remote host for the first time using VS Code's Remote SSH extension. The Remote SSH extension will use ssh commands to install the VS Code server side components on the remote host. The files for the server side component should be able to successfully install automatically so long as either the local host or the remote host has access to the internet. After the server side components are installed, you should be able to find the files in the .vscode-server folder. On a Linux host, this folder would be found in the /home// directory. On Windows, it should be found under the C:\Users<username>.vscode-server\ directory. You should be able to manually install the VS Code Server based on these instructions. If you run into any other errors, you can check if it is caused by a known version bug by comparing your error output with those described here. You might be able to resolve the problem simply by updating to a newer version of VS Code.
